# Replace odd and even occurrences of a pattern to another same pattern

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Having a scenario to replace the even and odd occurrence of backslashes by the number of quotient when dividing  by 2.

```
For example
Input: (15 backslashes)
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
output: (7 backslashes)
\\\\\\\

Input: (14 backslashes)
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
output: (7 backslashes)
\\\\\\\
```

I tried using sed command which is working for 4 backslashes to 2.
`sed 's/\\\\/\\/g'`

Appreciate if any help.

Comment: Do you have the string of backslashes in a variable? For instance, if you had `A='\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\' `, then `B=${#A}/2 ; echo ${A:0:$B}`

Comment: No. It's in a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another `sed` solution:

```sh
$ cat ip.txt
\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\
\\\\\\
\\\\\
\\\\
\\\
\\
\
$ sed -E 's/(\\+)\1\\?/\1/g' ip.txt
\\\\
\\\
\\\
\\
\\
\
\
\
```

`(\\+)\1\\?` will evenly divide the backslashes, the optional matching at the end will consume the last backslash for odd cases.

If single backslash should be removed instead of being preserved, use

```sh
sed -E 's/((\\+)\2)?\\?/\2/g'
```

Comment: Just curious to know. Is it possible to consider only odd occurrences and leave even occurrences untouched. ``For example
Input: (15 backslashes)
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
output: (7 backslashes)
\\\\\\\

Input: (14 backslashes)
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
output: (14 backslashes)
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\``

Comment: In that case, try `sed -E 's/(^|[^\\])(\\+)\2\\([^\\]|$)/\1\2\3/g'` or `perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)(\\+)\1\\(?!\\)/$1/g'`

Comment: sed -E 's/(^|[^\\])(\\+)\2\\([^\\]|$)/\1\2\3/g' not working for single backslash which is also odd occurrence.
```Input: (1 backslash) \ output: (0 backslash) Input: (3 backslashes) \\\ output: (1 backslash) \ Input: (5 backslashes) \\\\\ output: (2 backslashes) \\ Input: (7 backslashes) \\\\\\\ output: (3 backslashes) \\\ and so on...```

Comment: you can modify it using the `s/((\\+)\2)?\\?/\2/g` model mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 5):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
cat file

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

# using awk
awk '{print substr($0, 1, int(length($0)/2))}' file

\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\
```

Answer (score 3):

Using sed: in lines with an odd number of `\` first get rid of the last one. Then substitute pairs, as you did:

```
sed -r 's/((\\\\)*)(\\)?/\1/g;s/\\\\/\\/g'
```

Demo:

```
$ cat foo.txt
\\\\
\\\
\\
$ sed -r 's/((\\\\)*)(\\)?/\1/g;s/\\\\/\\/g' foo.txt
\\
\
\
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. Appreciate it.

Comment: @rowboat You're absolutely right. `sed 's/\\//;s/\\\\/\\/g'` does the same. I didn't see this one. Nice. And you are also right, my solution works for lines of backslashes but not for mixtures of backslashes and other strings. I just realized that this was not excluded by the OP. The OP should accept the much better answer by @Sundeep.

Comment: @rowboat I finally realized that adding the `g` flag to the first substitute command solves the issue with "\\\foo\\\". I fixed my answer accordingly, but @Sundeep answer is still more elegant and should be preferred. Then yours, because of compactness and smartness.

Comment: @Ranaud Pacalet Will it work if modify your command to replace only odd occurrences? i.e. leaving even occurrences untouched.

Comment: @Sen If you can have several occurrences per line, it will be difficult to adapt my solution. Prefer a modification of the much better solution proposed by @Sundeep: `sed -r 's/((\\+)\2)?\\/\2/g'` (if single backslash should be removed) else `sed -r 's/(\\+)\1\\/\1/g'`.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. This will work for any number of `/`slashes and will give half of the numbers.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS="" }
{
  val=""
  num=split($0,arr,"")
  till=(int(num/2))
  for(i=1;i<=till;i++){
    val=(val?val OFS:"")arr[i]
  }
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ OFS="" }                   ##Setting OFS to null here.
{
  val=""                          ##Nullifying val here.
  num=split($0,arr,"")            ##Splitting current line to arr with NULL delimiter.
  till=(int(num/2))               ##getting half of NF(number of fields) in till.
  for(i=1;i<=till;i++){           ##Traversing through fields till value of till.
    val=(val?val OFS:"")arr[i]    ##Creating val here which has array individual element value.
  }
  print val                       ##Printin val here.
}
' Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Sen, Your welcome, I also added detailed explanation for solution, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED. Try:

```
sed 's/\\//; s/\\\\/\\/g'
```

Explanation: first remove one backslash; then replace every pair with one backslash. The g at the end of the second command indicates you have to repeat the operation on whole the line. The backslashes need to be escaped. That's the reason why you write these everytime twice.

Comment: This is what the OP already tried. And it will output 8 backslashes for a 15 backslashes input, instead of the expected 7.

Comment: Yeah. It is not working for odd ones since I need to have odd and even as same.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: The PO didn't add the flag `g` at the end of the command. Thank you for pointing out the error. I didn't count correctly the amount of backslashes. I think I can fix it. I will edit my post

Answer (score 0):

Using perl, and [@Sundeep's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559324/7552) ip.txt file:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's{(\\+)}{"\\" x int(length($1)/2)}ge' ip.txt
\\\\
\\\
\\\
\\
\\
\
\
```

That replaces one backslash with zero backslashes.